# Scrapy callback function returning same result multiple times

Tags: for-loop, asynchronous, xpath, scrapy

I am very new to Scrapy and I can't manage to get the callback function work. I manage to get all the urls and I manage to follow them in the callback function but when I get the result I receive some results multiple times and many of the results are missing. What seems to be the problem?

```
import scrapy

from kexcrawler.items import KexcrawlerItem

class KexSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kex'
    allowed_domains = ["kth.diva-portal.org"]
    start_urls = ['http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/resultList.jsf?dswid=-855&language=en&searchType=RESEARCH&query=&af=%5B%5D&aq=%5B%5B%5D%5D&aq2=%5B%5B%7B%22dateIssued%22%3A%7B%22from%22%3A%222015%22%2C%22to%22%3A%222015%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22organisationId%22%3A%225956%22%2C%22organisationId-Xtra%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22publicationTypeCode%22%3A%5B%22article%22%5D%7D%2C%7B%22contentTypeCode%22%3A%5B%22refereed%22%5D%7D%5D%5D&aqe=%5B%5D&noOfRows=250&sortOrder=author_sort_asc&onlyFullText=false&sf=all']

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//li[@class="ui-datalist-item"]/div[@class="searchItem borderColor"]/a/@href'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    item = KexcrawlerItem()
    item['report'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="toSplitVertically"]/div[@id="innerEastCenter"]/span[@class="displayFields"]/span[@class="subTitle"]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

These are the first lines of the result:

```
{"report": ["On Multiple Reconnection ", "-Lines and Tripolar Perturbations of Strong Guide Magnetic Fields"]},
{"report": ["Four-Component Relativistic Calculations in Solution with the Polarizable Continuum Model of Solvation: Theory, Implementation, and Application to the Group 16 Dihydrides H2X (X = O, S, Se, Te, Po)"]},
{"report": ["On Multiple Reconnection ", "-Lines and Tripolar Perturbations of Strong Guide Magnetic Fields"]},
{"report": ["Comparing Vocal Fold Contact Criteria Derived From Audio and Electroglottographic Signals"]},
{"report": ["Four-Component Relativistic Calculations in Solution with the Polarizable Continuum Model of Solvation: Theory, Implementation, and Application to the Group 16 Dihydrides H2X (X = O, S, Se, Te, Po)"]},
{"report": ["Four-Component Relativistic Calculations in Solution with the Polarizable Continuum Model of Solvation: Theory, Implementation, and Application to the Group 16 Dihydrides H2X (X = O, S, Se, Te, Po)"]},
{"report": ["On Multiple Reconnection ", "-Lines and Tripolar Perturbations of Strong Guide Magnetic Fields"]},
{"report": ["Four-Component Relativistic Calculations in Solution with the Polarizable Continuum Model of Solvation: Theory, Implementation, and Application to the Group 16 Dihydrides H2X (X = O, S, Se, Te, Po)"]},
{"report": ["Dynamic message-passing approach for kinetic spin models with reversible dynamics"]},
{"report": ["RNA editing of non-coding RNA and its role in gene regulation"]},
{"report": ["Security monitor inlining and certification for multithreaded Java"]},
{"report": ["Security monitor inlining and certification for multithreaded Java"]},
{"report": ["On the electron dynamics during island coalescence in asymmetric magnetic reconnection"]},
{"report": ["On the electron dynamics during island coalescence in asymmetric magnetic reconnection"]},
{"report": ["On the electron dynamics during island coalescence in asymmetric magnetic reconnection"]},
{"report": ["On the electron dynamics during island coalescence in asymmetric magnetic reconnection"]},
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should never override the `parse` method in `scrapy` - that is where most of its implementation is

Comment: @gtlambert this is not true, you have to override the parse method because that is the entry point of scrapy. What you mean is when using `LinkExtractor`s: in this case you must not override the `parse` method because it has a default implementation which is required (or you can implement it yourself but in that case you do not need the built-in extractor engine).

Comment: @Agnes did you take a look at the URLs your `parse` method is feeding to new requests? Scrapy does not filter the results to be distinct but the URLs loaded. If you end up with some session-parameter in the URLs you can get multiple results. If you want to filter the results create a custom item exporter which marks already exported elements and filters them.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to replicate your error and could not. All of the urls were distinct. I logged each item at the level of INFO, and suppressed everything below that and found each report to also be unique. I did unindent your yield call, because it threw me an error and defined your item class, with one field. If you copied and pasted that directly from the terminal, then I assume it was the product of a print, not the log, which makes me think that maybe you have multiple print calls which are getting called at different times. Try writing the files somewhere and seeing if there are actually duplicates. To test if the urls were unique I extracted the elements from your xpath into a list called elem then:
`print len(elem)
 b = set()
 for e in elem:
    b.add(e)
 print len(b)`
You could try making a global list of items, and then add a function spider_closed, that will automatically be called when it closes, and then do the same on that list. Sets only contain unique elements, if there is a discrepancy then you are actually creating duplicates.